# I've been trying to make a chat-bot in python, but during the password retrieval it keeps looping the Password input statement. Is there a solution?

Tags: python

Earlier I was having a problem with the getpass command, after I got that fixed, no the code runs in a loop, my code is given below:

```
name=str(input("Hello, I am your personal assistant (Assistant Name), please identify yourself"))

while True:
       if len(name) !=0:
           from getpass import getpass
           print("Please Confirm your identity: ")
           password=getpass()
           if (password == 'root'):
               print ('Identity confirmed, welcome back, ',name)
           else:
              print ('could not verify identity')
       else:
         print ("could not identify user")

print("What would you like me to help you with today?")
```

With this code, what happens when I run it in the terminal is that, it asks for the password, if the passwords do not match, it just closes the terminal, I did not want this to happen, what I wanted was, if the password is incorrect, it should ask to re-enter the password, so I added a *while True* statement, even after doing this, the terminal still closes if the passwords do not match. 
Also, if the password is correct, it gives the following:

OUTPUT:

```
Hello, I am your personal assistant, please identify yourself:
     input: George
please confirm your identity:
     input: root

>>>identity confirmed, welcome back, name

>>>please confirm your identity:
>>>password:
```

And then it just loops in the password. What should I do?

Comment: You should add break statement where login was successful to break the loop.

Comment: You really need to go through this slowly in your head or with pen and paper. For example, what happens if `len(name) == 0`? It will print "could not identify user" in an endless loop…

Answer (score -1):

The below solution should work, there is no exit condition from the loop in your code. Also just to add getpass seems to hang when being used on Pycharm , should work fine in windows console.

```
import getpass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = str(input("Hello, I am your personal assistant (Assistant Name), please identify yourself"))
    pwd_confirmed = 0

    while (pwd_confirmed == 0):
        print("Please Confirm your identity: ")
        password =  getpass.getpass()
        if (password == 'root'):
            print('Identity confirmed, welcome back, ', name)
            pwd_confirmed = 1
        else:
            print('could not verify identity')

    print("What would you like me to help you with today?")
```

Comment: `pwd_confirmed` used before assignment, and you assign `1` to it in both `if` branches…

Comment: Placed the incorrect test script, which I have fixed now. Using getpass will still give issues in Pycharm , the console seems to hang. It should work fine in windows prompt.